# How to append to IRequestOptions.additionalHeaders in typed-rest-client?

Tags: typescript, typed-rest-client

I am using the typed-rest-client package with the latest typescript.  I don't understand the type of the `additionalHeaders` field of `IRequestOptions`. I have an initial set of additional headers, and when I connect to the REST service I receive a cookie.  I'd like to add that cookie to the list of already existing additional headers, but I can't figure out a way that compiles and works correctly with typescript. The options are in the private `#options` field, and using

```
this.#options.additionalHeaders.append({ Cookie: `X-DM-DST=${this.#token}`});
```

compiles correctly, but fails at runtime with "TypeError: Cannot create property 'Accept' on string '[object Object][object Object]'" which doesn't make any sense to me. Using `push` doesn't work either because `IHeaders` isn't a list of array.  How do I append to an `IHeaders` field?

Comment: Just to verify, you mean: [typed-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-rest-client), version 1.8.6?

Comment: I have typed-rest-client 1.8.5, I will upgrade my packages.

Answer (score 0):

It *sounds* like [this line of code](https://github.com/microsoft/typed-rest-client/blob/f21ab8a105826b64bf5c2df81e1f341537d273c0/lib/RestClient.ts#L168) is the root cause of the bug:

```js
    private _headersFromOptions(options: IRequestOptions, contentType?: boolean): ifm.IHeaders {
        options = options || {};
        let headers: ifm.IHeaders = options.additionalHeaders || {};
        headers["Accept"] = options.acceptHeader || "application/json";
```

It's easy enough to demonstrate this error in your browser console:

```
(function(){
  "use strict";
  "[object Object][object Object]"["Accept"] = "application/json";
}())
// Error: VM903:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'Accept' on string '[object Object][object Object]'
```

It looked like something in your code sample was off, but it took a while before it struck me... the function to add elements to an array is [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), not `.append` and the function to merge objects together is [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

I couldn't find an `append` function in `typed-rest-client`, and I'm not aware of an `append` function in the standard JS library (other than [`Element.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append))

Now, the string itself is very interesting. If you convert an object to a string, you usually end up with something like:

```
({}).toString() === "[object Object]"
```

In this case, though, the object string is **doubled**. There are probably several ways you could get to that particular string, but one way would be to add two objects together, like so:

```
{} + {} === "[object Object][object Object]"
```

I suspect that something like this is happening somewhere in your code. Whatever the `append` function is, I think it's adding two objects together rather than what I can only guess was the intent: merging two objects.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried push(), but it didn't work either.  I changed to append() later.  It turns out that the cookie header is handled automatically, so I can sidestep this problem entirely.   

I believe that the IHeader type inside typed-rest-client should contain an array, but don't have enough experience with typescript to be sure.

Comment: @jsparkes - [TypeScript is just JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html). According to the documentation and code source, the `IRequestOptions` argument is supposed to be an object. Standard JS objects don't have a function named `append`. I don't know what you are using, but it sounds like you are taking the dangerous approach of trying random things until they "work". I'd recommend you take some time to understand your tools, or you'll find yourself in a situation with a severe bug and no clue how to fix it.